# Form sends empty model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of Objects which I want to modify on my View, I have built a View Model to contain the list of objects:

```
public class TrainerListViewModel
    {
       public List<Trainer> Trainers { get; set; }
    }
```

and I send a list of Trainers to the view from the controller:

```
 public virtual ActionResult Social()
        {
            var Trainers = new TrainerListViewModel();

            Trainers.Trainers = (from t in _db.Trainers select t).ToList();

            return View(Trainers);
        }
```

and here is my view:

```
@model XStreamingFitness.ViewModels.TrainerListViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Social", "Participant", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trainers.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="formSep">

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Trainers[i].permissionPostFacebook)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Trainers[i].permissionPostFacebook)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Trainers[i].permissionPostFacebook)
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Save Settings" name="Submit" />
}
```

now here is the POST controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult Social(TrainerListViewModel Trainers)
        {

           return RedirectToAction("Profile");
        }
```

but everytime I submit, the Trainers model is empty and I am not sure why this could be happening.

Comment: If you intercept with fiddler, do you see data in the POST?

Comment: Yes, the information is being sent

Comment: Do you need any further help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked before here at SO I suggest you check [mvc3 submit model empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442953/mvc3-submit-model-empty), its the same principals as the problem you are having.

See the snippet from the post.

> I see people writing the following lambda expression modelItem =>
>   item.SomeProperty in their views very often and asking why the model
>   binder doesn't correctly bind collection properties on their view
>   models.
>
> This won't generate proper name for the checkbox so that the default
>   model binder is able to recreate the Settings collection. I would
>   recommend you reading the following [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) to better understand the
>   correct format that the model binder expects.

-*By Darin Dimitrov*

It is to do with the way you are building your form he goes to suggest you use Property Editor Templates for the Trainer object.

This should then work.

Hope it helps